# Floating point division- why does dividend needs to be less than divisor

Tags: floating-point

Why does the dividend is shifted right and exponent incremented once when dividend is greater than divisor in floating point division

Answer (score 0):

I think you are referring to the situation where the **significand part of** the dividend is greater than the **significand part of** the divisor.

The answer is simple: the significand of the result is destined to represent a value between 1 and 2. This significand is computed by dividing the significand of the dividend by the significand of the divisor, so it is better to prepare the dividend to be larger than the divisor so as to reach this result.

```
significand of dividend:      [1 … 2)

significand of divisor:       [1 … 2)

ratio if no preparation:      (0.5 … 2)

ratio after preparation step: [1 … 2)
```

(The result may also be an infinity or a denormal. These cases can be recognized by looking only at the expected exponent after the preparation in question has taken place. The preparation step is still necessary when the result turns out to be, say, infinity, because the result being infinity is determined by the fact that the exponent would have to be too large **for the number to be represented normalized, with a significand in [1 … 2)**.)

Comment: Thank you very much :), but what about divide overflow and this condition?

Comment: And also after shift right the significant part of the dividend must be less than significant part of divisor . Does that contradict your answer? Or am I taking it wrong?